WebStorm - npm install for docker node STUCK
I am using WebStorm for my next.js project and I'd like to use a fully containerized environment even for development, but when I want to execute npm install the installation is stuck for a long time, longer than 30 minutes.
Did someone have the same problem and was able to resolve it?


Two things had to be done to solve that issue:

Restarting the Docker daemon.
Removing the entry point from the docker-compose.yml file and moving it into the Dockerfile.

